# Show Wordpress posts for limited time (depending on the value of a custom field)

Tags: php, wordpress, date, custom-fields, duration

I want to show Wordpress posts for a limited time (1 or 2 weeks) after their publication. For the duration I've created a custom field (`advertorial_duur`) which has either value `1` (1 week) or `2` (2 weeks).

It displays some posts already, but not according to the duration I've set in the posts. I can't figure it out exactly but I think it now displays posts for just 1 week regardless of the custom field value.

So far I've produced this code:

```
<ul class="advertorials">
    <?php
    $advertorials = new WP_Query( 'cat=18' ); 

    while ($advertorials->have_posts()) :

        $advertorials->the_post();        

        if ( (current_time(timestamp) - get_the_time('U') - (get_settings('gmt_offset') * 3600) ) < ((int)get_post_custom_values( 'advertorial_duur' ))*(7*60*60*24))
        {
    ?>

    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Lees meer over: <?php the_title(); ?>">
        <div class="thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail') ?></div>
        <p class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <div class="clr"></div></a>
    </li>

    <?php } ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: *It displays some posts already, but not according to the duration I've set in the posts* is a weak error description. Try to precise this.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the plugin [Post Expirator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-expirator/) which lets you set the expiration date, how to expire, and the expiration category for the post/page. But it would not use the value of the custom field.